# scrapy FormRequest can't request a post

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to get a list description of a content. it is a javascript.
They use method='POST' to give me that info.
When i try to inspect the website in html..their is nothing about that description in it.. only a script. When the page loads *(onClick)* that the only time i see those description content in the html. But not in scrapy shell.

This is the Info i get from that page i'm requesting:

```
    General:
    Request URL:http://map.imobiliare.ro/map/serv/detalii
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:200 OK
    Remote Address:46.4.85.111:80
    Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

    Response headers:
    Cache-Control:private
    Content-Length:1944
    Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date:Thu, 12 Oct 2017 06:41:48 GMT
    Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
    X-AspNetMvc-Version:4.0
    X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

Request Headers:
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:50
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: ...
...
Referer:http://map.imobiliare.ro/map/home?pagenr=1&tranz=1&categ=4
User-Agent: ...
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data:
id_anunt=2754018&tranz=1&categ=4&mc=1&id_cautare=0
```

I tried to use FormRequest to get that info but it gives me a 500 http status.

This is the code that i used in scrapy shell:

```
data = {'id_anunt': '2754018', 'tranz': '1', 'categ': '4', 'mc': '1', 'id_cautare': '0'}

head = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'}

req = FormRequest(url="http://map.imobiliare.ro/map/serv/detalii", method='POST', formdata=data,
                  headers=head)

fetch(req)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the answer....and this is the way to get it.

```
        data = {'id_anunt': '2754018', 'tranz': '1', 'categ': '4', 'mc': '1', 'id_cautare': '0'}

        req = FormRequest.from_response(response, url="http://map.imobiliare.ro/map/serv/detalii", formdata=data,
                                        callback=self.description_items)

        yield req
```

you have to put in the response and the url that does the post too.

Comment: Maybe this will save someone else time! Don't forget all values must be strings! If you are using a numeric value, enclosed them in quotes.